# How to extract all columns of a data frame which contain a specific value in the first row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, unique, key-value

I have a data frame with measurements for multiple experiments. I would like to separate the data frame into multiple data frames each containing measurements from one experiment.

g1,g2,etc. are different molecules that i measure and i would like to keep this information as row names.

df1

|  | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g1 | 0 | 5 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 9 |
| g2 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 1 |

I have then another data frame with information on which experiment belongs to which measurement.

df2

| MeasurmentNr | ExperimentNr |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | e1 |
| a2 | e1 |
| a3 | e2 |
| a4 | e2 |
| a5 | e3 |
| a6 | e3 |

How to separate the data frame into multiple data frames with the same format?

I tried to do to it by matching the values, but that didn't work.

```
exp <- split(dataframe,factor(c("e1","e2","e3"), levels=c("e1","e2","e3")))
```

What i ended up doing is not an elegant solution and it also has many steps while i am sure it can be done in one step. I'm not good in R so i would be really happy if someone could explain to be a more elegant solution.

Here is my solution. I first reshaped the df2, than merged it with df1 and lastly split the columns to a new list where each experiment is a separate df.

```
test <- melt(as.data.frame(df2), id.vars = "MeasurmentNr")
colnames(test) <- test[1,]
test <- test[-1, ]
newnew <- rbind(test,df1)

new_df <- split.default(newnew, sub('\\+', '', newnew[1,]))
```

Comment: You had better to also provide the data code of df1 and df2.

Comment: use "dput" on df1 and df2, it will help people replicate your problem more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a separate data frame for each experiment.

```
text="a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
g1 0 5 7 2 1 9
g2 5 6 1 3 7 1"
df1=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names=1)
text="MeasurmentNr ExperimentNr
a1 e1
a2 e1
a3 e2
a4 e2
a5 e3
a6 e3"
df2=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
lapply(unique(df2$ExperimentNr), function(x) {
  filter(df2, ExperimentNr==x) %>% .$MeasurmentNr %>% df1[,.]
})

[[1]]
   a1 a2
g1  0  5
g2  5  6

[[2]]
   a3 a4
g1  7  2
g2  1  3

[[3]]
   a5 a6
g1  1  9
g2  7  1
```